# 0x Quote API Call returning makerAmount equal 0

Tags: 0x

I am trying to run this API call: https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0x2e1AD108fF1D8C782fcBbB89AAd783aC49586756&sellToken=0x580a84c73811e1839f75d86d75d88cca0c241ff4&sellAmount=10000000000000000000

This is the full returned value:

```
{
  "chainId": 137,
  "price": "0.816659249868949659",
  "guaranteedPrice": "0.808492657370260162",
  "estimatedPriceImpact": null,
  "to": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
  "data": "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",
  "value": "0",
  "gas": "266000",
  "estimatedGas": "266000",
  "gasPrice": "40000000000",
  "protocolFee": "0",
  "minimumProtocolFee": "0",
  "buyTokenAddress": "0x2e1ad108ff1d8c782fcbbb89aad783ac49586756",
  "sellTokenAddress": "0x580a84c73811e1839f75d86d75d88cca0c241ff4",
  "buyAmount": "8166592498689496593",
  "sellAmount": "10000000000000000000",
  "sources": [
    {
      "name": "SushiSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "QuickSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "ComethSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dfyn",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "mStable",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Curve",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "DODO_V2",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "DODO",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Curve_V2",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "WaultSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Polydex",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "ApeSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "FirebirdOneSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Balancer_V2",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "KyberDMM",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "LiquidityProvider",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "proportion": "1",
      "intermediateToken": "0x8f3cf7ad23cd3cadbd9735aff958023239c6a063",
      "hops": [
        "QuickSwap",
        "Balancer_V2"
      ],
      "name": "MultiHop"
    },
    {
      "name": "JetSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "IronSwap",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aave_V2",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Uniswap_V3",
      "proportion": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Synapse",
      "proportion": "0"
    }
  ],
  "orders": [
    {
      "makerToken": "0x8f3cf7ad23cd3cadbd9735aff958023239c6a063",
      "takerToken": "0x580a84c73811e1839f75d86d75d88cca0c241ff4",
      "makerAmount": "0",
      "takerAmount": "10000000000000000000",
      "fillData": {
        "tokenAddressPath": [
          "0x580a84c73811e1839f75d86d75d88cca0c241ff4",
          "0x8f3cf7ad23cd3cadbd9735aff958023239c6a063"
        ],
        "router": "0xa5e0829caced8ffdd4de3c43696c57f7d7a678ff"
      },
      "source": "QuickSwap",
      "sourcePathId": "",
      "type": 0
    },
    {
      "makerToken": "0x2e1ad108ff1d8c782fcbbb89aad783ac49586756",
      "takerToken": "0x8f3cf7ad23cd3cadbd9735aff958023239c6a063",
      "makerAmount": "8166592498689496593",
      "takerAmount": "115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935",
      "fillData": {
        "poolId": "0x0d34e5dd4d8f043557145598e4e2dc286b35fd4f000000000000000000000068",
        "vault": "0xba12222222228d8ba445958a75a0704d566bf2c8"
      },
      "source": "Balancer_V2",
      "sourcePathId": "",
      "type": 0
    }
  ],
  "allowanceTarget": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
  "sellTokenToEthRate": "1.929673719382614526",
  "buyTokenToEthRate": "0"
}
```

The issue is for order 0, `makerAmount` is 0, and for order 1, `takerAmount` is an exceedingly large number: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935

Any tips or fixes I can do on my side to avoid such behavior? (It seems only to happen when Multihop is turned on, but that is not a desirable fix for us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values under `orders` are just informational and legacy at this point. We will be completely removing them in the next major version of 0xAPI.

Everything required to execute the transaction is encoded in the `data` field.

You are correct that it occurs in MultiHop where the `MAX_UINT` represents "sell the entire balance" in the middle of a MultiHop trade.

How are you intending to use those values?

Comment: We are using `orders` to route our swaps at defibasket.org. I explored using the `data` field, but that would require us to know beforehand the exact buy or sell amounts, which is not always the case.

Comment: Jacob, could you share any timelines on when `orders` will be deprecated? Happy to share my use case in more detail in order to understand if there is a way to keep working with 0x.